# IndexError: tuple index out of range in coo_matrix

Tags: python, matrix, sparse-matrix

Im trying to store the output of coo_matrix into a dictionary in the format of "store[0,0] = 1" using

```
J = coo_matrix(Mat)
store = {}
for row, col, value in zip(J.row, J.col, J.data):
    store["{0}".format(row),"{1}".format(col)] = "{2}".format(value)
```

What is the mistake in this?

Comment: `"{1}".format(col)` doesn't work, because you are supplying only one value while the format string requires at least 2 (python starts counting at 0)

Answer (score 0):

While I have no idea what `coo_matrix` might be or do, the problem is in your string formats.

If you are really sure that you want to have a tuple of strings as dictionary key, you'd do

```
store["{}".format(row),"{}".format(col)] = "{}".format(value)
```

Things like `"{0}...{1}...{2}"` work with multiple arguments, for example

```
>>> '{0}, {1}, {2}'.format('a', 'b', 'c')
'a, b, c'
>>> '{}, {}, {}'.format('a', 'b', 'c')  # 2.7+ only
'a, b, c'
>>> '{2}, {1}, {0}'.format('a', 'b', 'c')
'c, b, a'
>>> '{2}, {1}, {0}'.format(*'abc')      # unpacking argument sequence
'c, b, a'
>>> '{0}{1}{0}'.format('abra', 'cad')   # arguments' indices can be repeated
'abracadabra'
```

(directly taken from https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-examples)

But why don't you just do `store[(row, col)] = value`?